# showing two options in combobox in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

        con.Open();

        //  // code for project name- id starts 
        string Sql_project_name = "select customer_name, customer_mobile1 from tb_customer";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_project_name, con);

        OleDbDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(DR);

        //begin adding line
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["customer_name"] = "Select Customer Details";

        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
        // end adding a line


        combo_project_name.DataSource = table;


        combo_project_name.DisplayMember = "customer_name";

        combo_project_name.Text = "Select Customer Details";
```

In this code I am showing customer_name that is being fetched from database...but I want to show customer_mobile_number with it in the same combobox with comma between customer_name and customer_mobile...how can i achieve this....

Answer (score 1):

Change your query as

```
string Sql_project_name =  
select customer_name + ' , ' + customer_mobile1 as CombinedName from tb_customer`
```

and change your Combo-box display member as

```
combo_project_name.DisplayMember = "CombinedName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    con.Open();

    //  // code for project name- id starts 
    string Sql_project_name = "select customer_name + ', ' + customer_mobile1 as customer_name_and_mobile  from tb_customer";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_project_name, con);

    OleDbDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(DR);

    //begin adding line
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["customer_name"] = "Select Customer Details";

    table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    // end adding a line

    combo_project_name.DataSource = table;
    combo_project_name.DisplayMember = "customer_name_and_mobile";
    combo_project_name.Text = "Select Customer Details";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try another method of populating the combobox. Instead of using the datasource  property, manually loop into the queried data and add them into the combobox like this.

```
combo_project_name.Items.Clear();
for (x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
combo_project_name.Items.Add(customer_name + ", " + customer_mobile1);
}
```

Or you can combine the results using SQL itself like this...

```
SELECT customer_name + ', ' + customer_mobile1 as NewFieldName FROM tb_customer;
```